# Entry delimiter of JSON files for Hive table

Tags: json, hadoop, hive

We are collecting JSON data (public social media posts in particular) via REST API invocations, which we plan to dump into HDFS, then abstract a Hive table on top it using SerDe. I wonder though what would be the appropriate delimiter per JSON entry in a file? Is it new line ("\n")? So it would look like this:

```
{ id: entry1 ... post: }
{ id: entry2 ... post: }
...
{ id: entryn ... post: }
```

How about if we encounter a new line character within the JSON data itself, for example in `post`?

Comment: make the entire file contents a valid json array, then use jackosn json streaming api to parse with a custom serialiser to obtain parsed output of rawjson for each individual json object within the array

Comment: @Hector Can you give some pseudo-code or snippets? I am not yet that much familiar to Jackson library.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The best way would be one record per line, separated by "\n" exactly as you  guessed. 
This also means that you should be careful to escape "\n" that may be inside the JSON elements.
Indented JSON won't work well with hadoop/hive, since to distribute processing, hadoop must be able to tell when a records ends, so it can split processing of a file with N bytes with W workers in W chunks of size  roughly N/W.
The splitting is done by the particular InputFormat that's been used, in case of text, TextInputFormat. 
[TextInputFormat](https://hadoop.apache.org/docs/r2.6.2/api/org/apache/hadoop/mapred/TextInputFormat.html) will basically split the file at the first instance of "\n" found after byte  i*N/W (for i from 1 to W-1).
For this reason, having other "\n" around would confuse Hadoop and it will give you incomplete records.

As an alternative, I wouldn't recommend it, but if you really wanted you could use a character other than "\n" by configuring the property "textinputformat.record.delimiter" when reading the file through hadoop/hive, using a character that won't be in JSON (for instance, \001 or CTRL-A is commonly used by Hive as a field delimiter) but that can be tricky since it has to also be supported by the SerDe. 
Also, if you change the record delimiter, anybody who copies/uses the file on HDFS must be aware of the delimiter, or they won't be able to parse it correctly, and will need special code to do it, while keeping "\n" as a delimiter, the files will still be normal text files and can be used by other tools.

As for the SerDe, I'd recommend this one, with the disclaimer that I wrote it :)
https://github.com/rcongiu/Hive-JSON-Serde

Comment: Does your SerDe allows partitioned tables?

Comment: Yes, it does. I just double checked.

Comment: I have another question for you, although I already posted it somewhere. I want to use your SerDe so that the Hive table can be accessed as a datasource by Tableau (via SparkSQL-Thrift Server). I wonder how can I add the SerDe jar when I start Thrift Server so that Tableau can read the Hive table based on JSON? If you have an answer, kindly post it on this topic, "Adding Hive SerDe jar on SparkSQL Thrift Server". Thanks.