# How to split concatenated JSON files using C#

Tags: c#, json.net

I've got to process files that are full of JSON objects. These have simply been concatenated together with no separator thus making the whole file invalid JSON. What is the best way to split this up again? I need to ensure that I don't end up splitting in encoded strings and it needs to be fairly fast as the file can be quite big.

Example file:

```
{"property":"Data which may include}{"}{"property":"A second object"}
```

Comment: Having a hard time understanding why someone would willingly create invalid JSON. What I would do is make a copy of the file, use the 'find and replace' option on any text editor and replace the concantenation with nothing. Then, I would use JSON.Net to do the rest.

Comment: Can you try splitting them by opening and closing brackets ? I think that way you can split them by valid JSON objects

Comment: looking at your StackOverflow reputation the problem looks bigger can you please explain more about the problem

Comment: This needs to be automated. It is coming out of a logging system in huge quantities.

Comment: @DimitarTsonev Split this: `{"foo":"}"}`

Comment: Do you need to specifically split them, or you want to just read and process them with JSON.NET?

Comment: @RudreshaParameshappa before making broad assumptions, cloud services and big data software uses *streaming JSON* or *newline-delimited JSON* files for a reason

Comment: I just want to read and process them.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26601594/what-is-the-correct-way-to-use-json-net-to-parse-stream-of-json-objects

Comment: You could use a tokenizer from JSON.Net.

Comment: Could you do a String.Replace("{''}", ""), and then deserialize?

Comment: @MartinBrown if the delimiter is a newline, as in most such files, *don't* try to deserialize all of it at once. This format is meant to be processed a line at a time for scalability reasons. Just use `StringReader.ReadLine` and parse the line with JSON.NET. You'll be able to parse GB-sized files with only a few KBs this way

Comment: If you know that the result file consists of valid JSON objects, which are just contatenated, you can fairly easy split them by counting the number of opening and closing brackets, no ?

Comment: @Dimitar no, look at the example JSON given by the OP. The string `"}"` is a valid value.

Comment: @MartinBrown On the other hand, if someone tried to "fix" the data by removing newlines, you lose any performance benefit - the reason streaming json formats are fast is precisely that they *don't* need complex parsing. Did you post the *actual* string? Is this the entire payload or just one line of it? Perhaps someone decided to remove the record's outer braces?

Comment: @PanagiotisKanavos delimiters are not required for efficient parsing of json "stream". Parser can just parse object from opening to closing brace (and then repeat that until end of file, one object at a time).

Comment: @EVk line-delimited files don't *need* a parser to detect a record. That's how file splitting in Hadoop or Spark works - a very simple reader can split the file across line boundaries and send blocks to multiple parsers without knowing anything about the record format. This scales to TB-sized files

Comment: @Evk [similar question here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33820906/entry-delimiter-of-json-files-for-hive-table)

Comment: @PanagiotisKanavos I don't say delimiters are bad, just that they are not required (because you said above that you are losing all perfomance benefits without them, with which I don't agree). But I see your point, it's good that you don't need parser and can split processing with delimiters.

Comment: @Evk the question I linked explains why that should only be used as a last resort. It's a Hadoop/Hive question, not a JSON.NET question. You can easily split a GB or TB-sized file in 100 or 1000 by simply seeking to the boundary index and seek until you find a delimiter. You can then use multiple parsers at once to parse individual batches

Answer (score 0):

I've done a lot of parsing like this. There's so much JSON code out there that it's rarely necessary with JSON. But if you really need to pass this code yourself in C#, I see no way to approach this other than by manually parsing it character by character.

Special attention needs to be given to curly braces and colons. And, when parsing tokens you'll need to determine if it's quoted. If it's quoted, then you go until the closing quote (ignore any escaped quotes). If it's not quoted, then you go until you hit a non-symbol character.

You might find this task a little easier using my [Text Parsing Helper Class](http://www.blackbeltcoder.com/Articles/strings/a-text-parsing-helper-class) class to handle some of the lower-level string handling of your parser.

Comment: On the contrary, big data services, cloud services use newline-delimited or more broadly, json delimited files, *precisely* to avoid parsing the entire 10GB file before processing entries

Comment: @PanagiotisKanavos: I'm not sure exactly which point you are taking exception to. The delimiters don't mean you don't have to parse the file (although it may be more efficient).